# One Apache Tomcat application server with 2 configured war applications and a MessageSource exception

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, tomcat8

I have an Apache Tomcat application server, version 8.5.30, and it has 2 web applications configured on it.

These applications have Spring Framework 5 and each one has its own ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource because I use internationalization of messages (i18n).

When I start Apache and load one of the sites, the site that was opened first has its messages loaded into memory, and the second site when I open doesn't have its messages loaded. So this causes an exception message on second application and throws an exception like:

> Caused by: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException :
>   No message found under code 'menu.login' for locale 'en_US'.

To try to solve this problem, I tried to create two different MessagesSources, one for each application, but when loading the application server another exception was thrown:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.context.MessageSource] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: messageSourceA,
>   messageSourceB.

**Some example about how I tried to do**

AppA in ROOT.war (alias 1)

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSourceA() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath*:messageA", "classpath*:enumaratorA");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

AppB in ROOT.war (alias 2)

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSourceB() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath*:messageB", "classpath*:enumaratorB");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Please, could you help me to solve this problem?
How can I make the Apache/Spring understand that they are two different sources?
What other options can be made?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these two applications sharing the same war file? Tomcat is pretty good about keeping the classpath of individual wars separate. Review the Class Loader How to doc here and compare to your environment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try for this to work.

Assuming properties files are stored at project's `src/main/resources` package. Please remove file suffix `.properties` so that only `messageB` and `enumeratorB` remains in  `messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messageB", "classpath:enumaratorB");` and double check file path and spelling.

If your properties files are in classpath, please use `classpath*:` otherwise Spring will look for properties in web directory of your application.

Comment: My properties files are inside the "src/main/resources". I tried to make your suggestions, but unfortunately the error continues. I have edited the question so that it shows the current state of the doubt.